# Precommit Hook is running prettier command on the folder which is not mentioned in the prettier command

Tags: prettier, pre-commit-hook, husky

I have a command in package.json:

```
"prettier:fix": "npx prettier backend --write"
```

Now I have setup eslint-staged as:

```
"lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,json}": [
      "npm run prettier:fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
```

and husky precommit-hooks as:

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  }
```

Now the issue is that when I change a file in frontend folder, the prettier is run on files placed in frontend folder as well, despite the fact that I have already given the folder name, i.e., backend, on which to run the prettier command.

Comment: `lint-staged` passes the list of files which were changed to the commands it calls, that's the point of it.

Comment: So the prettier command will be run on the files passed by lint-staged rather than the paths mentioned in the prettier command?

Comment: It will run on _both_, the complete command would be something like `npx prettier backend --write frontend/changed.js`. Have a look at the output, `npm run prettier:fix` should log its arguments.